# Rails - only_path provides the full URL for a link. How can you obtain the variable outside of link_to?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

When using link_to:

```
<%= link_to('View', group_url(136, :only_path => false)) %>
```

You can use only_path to get a url output with http://www.site.com/groups/1

Where without only_path, you get /groups/1

How can I get just the path in rails? outside of a link_to? How do you get: http://www.site.com

Reason why is I want to create hash deep linked URLs, so I'm thinking about doing:

```
<%= link_to('View', XXXXXX + "#" +group_url(136, :only_path => true)) %>
```

Where XXXXXX is the url, http://www.site.com

Which would then give me what I want:

```
http://www.site.com/#/groups/1
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

`request.host` to return host ("www.your_site.com")

`request.protocol` to return protocol, for example `http://` or `https//`

`request.host_with_port` to return port with host ("www.your_site.com:3456")

```
<%= link_to('View', request.host + "#" +group_url(136, :only_path => true)) %>
<%= link_to('View', request.protocol + request.host + "#" +group_url(136, :only_path => true)) %>
<%= link_to('View', request.protocol + request.host_with_port + "#" +group_url(136, :only_path => true)) %>
```

**EDIT**

hack:

```
host = group_url(136).gsub(/#{group_url(136, :only_path => true)}/, "")
```

or

```
url  = group_url(136)
path = group_path(136)
host = url.gsub(/#{path}/, "")
```

Comment: Thanks fl00r but I don't think I can use request.host as I need this for a user_mailer email template view, which lans in user's inbox. Right?

Comment: And why you didn't notice that in your question? It is importaint informaiton.

Comment: Sorry, I just tested this and the mailer errors with: undefined method `protocol' for nil:NilClass

Answer (score 0):

In a controller, `request.env['HTTP_HOST']` will contain the host part of the request that came in, so you could create a helper method to return a properly formatted "base url" doing something like this:

```
def site_root_url
  if request.env['HTTPS'] == 'on'
    proto = 'https'
  else
    proto = 'http'
  end
  "#{proto}://#{request.env['HTTP_HOST']}"
end
```

Comment: Thanks, but that isn't rendering the http:// or the https:// based on the environment. which only_path in the link_to helper does?

Comment: just use `request.protocol` for that.

Comment: Yeah I just saw that in your answer, thats convenient!